# find exact word in Flutter, Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to find the exact word or character in Dart?

```
List<Type> _media = [
    Device(one: 'abc', two: 'News'),
    Device(one: 'bc', two: 'Television')
];
```

Since I am trying to query values in class
my code is like this

```
  String Query(String value) {
    return _media
        .where((medium) => medium.one.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()))
        .map((medium) => (medium.two)).toString();
```

If I put 'bc' as value, the result I expect to get is 'Television' not 'News'
It may be because I used **contain**.

Regex seems to be working but my code doesn't work at all :(

```
  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(
    r"(?<![\w\d])abc(?![\w\d])",
    caseSensitive: false,
    multiLine: false,
  );

  String Query(String value) {
    return _media
        .where((medium) => medium.one.toLowerCase().regExp.hasMatch(value))
        .map((medium) => (medium.two)).toString();
```

Would you guys help me find a solution? :)

Comment: Why don't you filter like `.where((medium) => medium.one.toLowerCase() == value)`?

Comment: Omg, it is a way easy solution to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` does not have a `regExp` attribute, that's why it does not work. You should call `hasMatch()` on the `regExp` object:

```
_media.where((medium) => regExp.hasMatch(medium.one))
```

(you don't need `toLowerCase()` because your regexp is already case insensitive)

But if all you need is the string match, you can do just that:

```
_media.where((medium) => medium.one.toLowerCase() == value)
```